# Does Backbone Forms supports file types?

Tags: backbone-forms

I just wanted to know if Backbone Forms supports file type, like:

```
Models.Mensaje = Backbone.Model.extend({
    schema: {
        contenido: { validators: ['TextArea', 'required'] },
        remitente: { validators: ['required'] },
        destinatario: { validators: ['required'] },
        adjunto: { type: 'File', editorClass: "form-control" }
    }
});
```

or something similar

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one built in however it would be relatively easy to implement as a custom editor (see https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms#custom-editors).

There are also some user-contributed custom editors which deal with file uploads here which could at least serve as an example/starting point:

https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms/wiki/Custom-Editors

For example, have a look at the Filepicker one:

https://gist.github.com/philfreo/3877309